# I am a sport - underground plus something round

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> I am a sport
> My first part is underground
> My second part is something round
>
> Some hit people and they're as blind as a bat
>
> **What sport am I?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer

> **Baseball**

> I am a sport

> **Baseball** is a sport.

> My first part is underground

> A base can be underground

> My second part is something round

> A ball is round.

> Some hit people and they're as blind as a bat

> Baseballs have hit people before. A bat hits the baseball.

Answer (score 3):

This might not be the intended answer, but it feels like a good alternative: You are

> karate.

> My first part is underground

> A "karat" pronounced as "carrot" grows underground.

> My second part is something round

> The letter "e" is round...

Comment: I thought of something different. Not the correct answer!

Comment: @misc544 ...although I just became a Shotokan karate-ka